# Keycloak spring boot configuration for client roles

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have a spring boot enabled rest api configured with keycloak.

```
keycloak.realm = demo
keycloak.realmKey = yfdsfdiufuydhf
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.resource = lib-backend
keycloak.bearer-only = true
keycloak.credentials.secret = a9fa2e60-324b-4508-b33d-84be2a981da3
# Keycloak Enable CORS
keycloak.cors = true

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name = spring secured api
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].authRoles[0] = lib_sadmin
```

The above code will return api to client without any issue.But when i remove the realm role and enabled the client role gives 403 forbidden error.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to operate with the client roles, you should add this to your configuration:

```
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
```

See the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/).

Comment: Yousssir, saved my day!

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I found where the `keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings` flag is documented: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_java_adapter_config

Answer (score 0):

keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true does not work as it returns 403.  If the @RolesAllowed is set to the realm role and keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=false it is able to see the roles and works as expected.  This is the link to the change request that is not resolved yet https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-8376

Comment: Code formatting required